# How do I make a Logitech c525 HD webcam work?

Tags: 11.04, webcam

How do I make a Logitech c525 HD webcam work?

Comment: Can you plug it in and run a video program and then update your question with what happens?

Answer (score 6):

install cheese from software center or synatic or plug-in your webcam & run this command in terminal

```
gstreamer-properties
```

Or if you have ffmpeg installed then you can use this command

```
ffplay -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jahid65's answer, if the webcam is plugged into a usb 3.0 socket try using a usb 2.0 socket([or vice versa](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1206.3/03155.html)).  This got it working for me.